# Laravel database session not working when setting a session domain

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies

I encounter issues with the database driver in order to store sessions cookies:

The database connection is currently working but cookies are not set in the browser however session data are in my database.

**I have run:**

```sh
php artisan session:table
```

**Set database session in my `.env` file:**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

Bellow the `config/session.php` file:

```php
[
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'connection' => 'mysql',
    'table' => 'sessions',
]
```

**EDIT 1:**

The route in `web.php`:

```php
Route::group(['domain' => GetDomainInfo::GetDomainName(), 'middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', "HomeController@index");
});
```

## Solved issue by :

I have created for example a localhost domain: **webcv** by adding to my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 webcv.local
127.0.0.1 admin.webcv.local
```

Set the session domain to : **.webcv.local** in **config/session.php** like so:

```php
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', ".webcv.local"),
```

Or just by adding in the `.env` file:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.webcv.local
```

Now I can access to both `webcv.local` and `admin.webcv.local` with the same cookie.

Comment: Please, provide more info about the problem. What's the error?

Comment: there is no error but when i check the cookies on the browser there is nothing is stored

Comment: `php artisan session:table`

`composer dump-autoload`

`php artisan migrate`

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar i have already run these commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with the database driver for sessions, you have to create the session table.

I'll assume you already scaffold the native authentication system by doing `php artisan make:auth` and migrated the migrations.

So first you generate the migration, and then migrate:

`php artisan session:table`

Execute the migration:

`php artisan migrate`

Obviously, this won't work if the routes you're checking on, aren't using the `web` middleware.
If you're not registering the routes in `/routes/web.php`, then you have to manually specify the `web` middleware for them. Either in your controller's constructor, or directly in the route itself.

**Edit after fix for future reference:**

Also, check your domain in `config/session.php` is the same you're using in development or production, depending where you are working on.

Comment: thanks but i have already run php artisan session:table composer dump-autoload php artisan migrate

Comment: @loic.lopez have you already checked your route is running under `web` middleware? Are you using laravel native auth system? Have you already logged in with registered account?

Comment: yes i use laravel Auth system take a look to my edit

Comment: @loic.lopez the problem is with that domain. Can you do a `dd( GetDomainInfo::GetDomainName() )` BEFORE that route group, and tell me what does that output? It has to be the same as the one you have in `config/session.php` => `'domain' => '.yourdomain.com'` . If that works I'll edit my question.
Also, remember to clear the cookies / re-sign-in after changing anything on that file

Comment: i have running `dd(config('session.domain'));` results to `".webcv"`and `dd(GetDomainInfo::GetDomainName()); `results to `"webcv"` "webcv" is my primary localhost domain

Comment: @loic.lopez There it is then, that's the problem! Use `'domain' => '.'.GetDomainInfo::GetDomainName()`

Comment: i solved the issue by replacing my localhost domain : "webcv" by "webcv.local"

Comment: Yes, the domain was the problem indeed. I'll edit my answer for future reference.

Comment: just a little question : why laravel need a .local for exemple to get it work ?

Comment: I guess it doesn't. But you must have been working under `webcv.local` domain in your development machine. That's why. Although the cookie should be accessible for any subdomain if you set it as `.webcv.local` in your `session.php` file

Comment: In `localhost:8000` your domain is `localhost:8000` and cookie domain `.localhost:8000`

Comment: I do not use php artisan serve, i have a nginx server, but i solve this issue by adding a fake TLD : **.local** to my local domain, before adding this fake TLD the cookie has for domain : **webcv** while i had put `'domain' => '.webcv'` to config/session.php